# Quicker increase in breathing rate due to stretching/engaging tired muscles

Tags: blood-pressure, breathing, sports, fatigue, stretching

After exercise or after eating too much food (or both) I usually become tired. I regularly observe that if I strech or engage major muscles (chest or legs) my breathing rate quickens considerably in the space of just a few seconds (which is different when I'm not tired). Is this due to low blood pressure or a slow blood circulation?

I'm mainly asking this out of curiosity, and I'm not sure if anyone else has observed a similar effect. I can't come up with a satisfying explanation myself.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. Let's say you go out and exercise and then rest until your breathing and heart rate are back to normal. If you then stretch major muscle groups, your respiratory rate increases. The same thing happens if you eat a large meal before stretching. But if you do the same stretching without prior exercise or food, your breathing remains normal. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Although "back to normal" might not be technically correct, since the body is regenerating/digesting, which requires blood, oxygen and energy.

Comment: Understood, but I meant your respiratory and heart rates only. Those are back to normal resting levels, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Maybe you could borrow a heart-rate monitor (like the ones that can be strapped to your chest), then post the data here in your question? This seems like a difficult situation to explain, and there could be many factors involved.

Comment: Also, some detailed descriptions (including duration) of the stretches involved could help, since some stretching can come close to exertion (e.g. dynamic stretches or yoga positions).

Comment: This is an "I observed X phenomenon, what is it?" identification type of question, which I think is going to be off topic in our new scope...